# Dart: Iterable Extension to Remove an item

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating an Iterable extension in dart to mimick most of the methods of List.
However, when trying to remove an item from an iterable, I sometimes run into a problem where I can't remove specific types of objects.

The code below works for native types such as int,string, but not for custom types

```html
extension Iterables<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<E> remove(E item) {
    try {
      return toList()..remove(item);
      // this.removeWhere((p0) => p0 == item);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

**To be clear:** I want this to be a void function instead of creating a new copy!

Thanks!

**The problem I'm trying to solve:**

```html
// my collection is a list
List<myType> x = [...manyItems]
x.map(someMap).toList();

// I want it to be an Iterable instead so that I don't have to do .toList()

// My iterable extension is missing the remove capabilities the list class has
```

Comment: Why are you converting to a list rather than just `filter`ing out the elements you don't want?

Comment: I tried doing that with .removeWhere, but I still receive the error: "type 'MappedListIterable<myType, myType>' is not a subtype of type 'List<myType>' in type cast"

Comment: `removeWhere` is still a `List` and not an `Iterable` method. Why not use the `Iterable` method `where` (and negate the condition)?

Comment: post the complete code of your extension: what you have sent cannot even compile as `removeWhere` is not an `Iterable` method

Comment: my bad... 'removeWhere' is an iterable extension, which I mistook for a list extension! My actual attempt is converting the iterable to a list then using remove()

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? why would you want to convert it to a list and then remove an item?

Comment: @pskink I have a big collection of objects which I update every second using .map and then, to convert it back to a list I use .toList(). My goal is to replace the list with an iterable, so that I don't have to do .toList() every time.

Comment: "My goal is to replace the list with an iterable, so that I don't have to do .toList() every time" - `map()` method already returns an `Iterable` so I still don't understand what's your goal

Comment: @pskink Yes it does, but the collection I work it requires me to have a .remove() method, which iterables don't have. Sure, I can make an extension that returns Iterable but I'm looking for a void function solution. I edited my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with custom types and the remove method is not working as expected, chances are the equality comparison is failing.

In this case, you should do one of the below:

1. Override the == operator and hashCode property in your custom class to ensure correct equality comparisons.
2. Use the [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package.

Below is a sample on how to do option 1 mentioned above:

```
class CustomType {
  final int id;

  CustomType(this.id);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
    return other is CustomType && other.id == id;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

Some random tip:

A better way to make the code more readable and idiomatic - consider using the `where` method directly, as it is more declarative and clear about creating a new `Iterable`.

```
extension Iterables<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<E> remove(E item) {
    return this.where((e) => e != item);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great, except I don't want to override the == operator for every type.

Comment: Your other option is to use the Equatable package, to ensure deep equality.

Answer (score 0):

The "custom types" used in this methods needs to be equal and if you don't override the `operator ==` or the `hashCode` of these classes, dart considers two "custom types" equals if the instance of object is the same.

Saying that, you can:

1. override the [operator ==](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html);
2. make them extends/implements [Comparable](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.3/dart-core/Comparable-class.html); or
3. uses [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) (that's what I use).